# First element of the array $$foo

Tags: php, arrays

I'm in trouble with this one. I've got a bunch of arrays decide on runtime which one I want to use with the double '$'.

So if `$foo` is `'bar'`, I get the array `$bar` with `$$foo`.

This works fine but how do I get the first element of $bar? $bar[0] is the way, but `$$foo[0]` simply doesn't give any output.

Can anyone help me?

(I know it's a really bad style but the code is already done by someone else and I have to extend it here and there. I'm not going to rewrite all the code structure ;-)

Comment: `$$foo[0]` should give you output, even if it's just a **Notice** message about `b` being an undefined variable. This would be a hint at what's going wrong.

Comment: @salathe by default there will be no output. You have to explicitly configure PHP to notify you when you read unset variables.

Comment: @meagar that depends on which "default" you mean. Aside from that, anyone having problems with their code, leading to asking a question here, should at least have all errors being reported and displayed.

Comment: @salathe I mean the one and only default, the *default*. It's called a default for a reason, and it's `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`. If your `error_reporting` is set to something else, it is *by definition* set to a non-default value.

Comment: @meagar, the one and only default is not that at all, sorry.

Comment: @salathe Keep making baseless assertions, that's really helping your case. Meanwhile, here in the real world, here's the PHP manual backing up my side. Note the line starting with "In PHP 4 and PHP 5 the **default value**..." http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: @meagar, as of PHP 5.3.0 the "default" value is `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE` regardless of what the manual says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use braces around the inner `$foo`:

```
echo ${$foo}[0];
```

You can do the same when the sub-variable in a variable-variable expansion is more complex:

```
$array1 = array('a');
$array2 = array('b');
$array3 = array('c');

// writes 'abc'
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i)
  echo ${'array' . $i}[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Please do not do this.  [Variable-variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) are **always** a bad idea.  There are better ways of solving the problem (such as arrays).  Using the variable variables makes your code murkier and harder to understand.  Not to mention potential security impacts it may have.  Just avoid them, it's better in the long run...

Note that I'm only talking about variable variables, not variable object members and methods (`$foo->$bar` and `$foo->$method()`)...  I use them all the time (although even that has some drawbacks).

Comment: I know it's a really bad style but the code is already done by someone else and I have to extend it here and there. I'm not going to rewrite all the code structure ;-)

Comment: @septi: that's no reason not to rewrite the code.  Remember, by not rewriting it you're accumulating [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).  The professional and best way to handle it is to clean up the code when you find messes like this.  Otherwise you're going to cost yourself significant issues in the long run.  Remember, maintainability is paramount, so it's better to put a little more effort in now to fix the mess than to just leave it for later when the cost will rise.  It'll never get easier to correct than now (but it will get harder)...

Comment: IMO, variable variables aren't always a bad idea. Sometimes it can reduce amount of code if used wisely.

Comment: @galymzhan: Can you provide a single example where variable-variables solve a problem **better** than an array could?  I have yet to see one.  If you can provide one that's truly better, I will alter my statement.  But I have never seen it, and I've never talked to anyone who could provide me a solid example...  So as it stands, all the evidence points to *yes, they are a bad idea*...

Comment: just one example I can remember: https://gist.github.com/1188637 . Basically, anywhere where you want to access variable names dynamically

Comment: @galymzhan: You can solve that better [using reflection (example)](https://gist.github.com/1188649] The reason it's better is that you only write your parameters once, in the header.  You don't need to maintain multiple copies of them, so you're actually reducing duplication (which is what you said variable-variables can do).  So I still stand behind my original statement...

Comment: And one other way you could solve it without variable-variables and without reflection would be to use Compact: https://gist.github.com/1188670 (via @Nikic)...  So there are other ways with distinct benefits over variable-variables...

Comment: @ircmaxell Yes, pretty good solution. Anyway, code with variable variables looks more simple and elegant to me, that's why I think they can be useful sometimes without hurting readability, maintainability and performance. Code similar to what I posted was in production and nobody had any problems reading it.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm in trouble

indeed you are.

> I've got a bunch of arrays

That's your problem.
Array should be ONE. A nested one.
So, you will need just

```
$data[$foo][0]
```

Comment: You're right, but as I said, I'm just extending the code from someone else and definitely will not rewrite the whole stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = $$foo;
echo $var[0]; // do whatever you want with that
```